# mySQL Exclude entire result if GROUP_CONCAT returns NULL

Tags: mysql

If this is a dupe, I apologize. I couldn't find it.

I have this convoluted query that hits 3 tables, and I need to figure out how to exclude an entire result if the `GROUP_CONCAT` as `shows` returns NULL (which it does often). To clarify, if `shows` comes up `NULL`, then I don't want any of the `profile` data for that result either. I want the entire row skipped.

```
SELECT
  `profiles`.*,
  IF( `profiles`.`profile_id` IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT (`badges`.`profile_id`)
    FROM `badges`
  ), TRUE, FALSE ) AS `has_registrations`,
  (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `shows`.`show_name` SEPARATOR '<br>' )
    FROM `shows`
    LEFT JOIN `badges` ON `badges`.`show_id` = `shows`.`show_id`
    WHERE
      `badges`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id` 
      AND `shows`.`end_date` >= CURDATE()
  ) AS `shows`
FROM `profiles`
```

Also accepting input on speed/elegance of the overall query.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a more efficient way to do this but I think a simple where clause will do the trick.

```
SELECT
  `profiles`.*,
  IF( `profiles`.`profile_id` IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT (`badges`.`profile_id`)
    FROM `badges`
  ), TRUE, FALSE ) AS `has_registrations`,
  (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `shows`.`show_name` SEPARATOR '<br>' )
    FROM `shows`
    LEFT JOIN `badges` ON `badges`.`show_id` = `shows`.`show_id`
    WHERE
      `badges`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id` 
      AND `shows`.`end_date` >= CURDATE()
  ) AS `shows`
FROM `profiles`
where `shows` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses, so **WHERE ... shows ...** will not work https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: Hi @nacho, Are sure? it seams to me that the query is only using the group by in a subquery

Comment: Yes, it only uses a GROUP BY in the subquery. What i am trying to say is that you cannot use aliases (show is an alias) in a WHERE clause because **"Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a having clause:

```
SELECT
  `profiles`.*,
  IF( `profiles`.`profile_id` IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT (`badges`.`profile_id`)
    FROM `badges`
  ), TRUE, FALSE ) AS `has_registrations`,
  (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `shows`.`show_name` SEPARATOR '<br>' )
    FROM `shows`
    LEFT JOIN `badges` ON `badges`.`show_id` = `shows`.`show_id`
    WHERE
      `badges`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id` 
      AND `shows`.`end_date` >= CURDATE()
  ) AS `shows`
FROM `profiles`
having shows is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand questions correctly, you don't need null values. Perhaps the null value occurs due use of left join why don't you try with inner join their will be no null values.